# How to display huge amount of data by a gridview in asp.net by NOT selecting entire data from datasource?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, pagination

how can I create a query in order to select some records every time user wanna to display them  into a gridview. I don't want to select all entire records from my data source. What I exactly want is to simulate pagination by query.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

[Efficient Paging for GridView](http://www.nikhedonia.com/notebook/entry/efficient-paging-for-gridview/)

Comment: This answer is a dead link.